# Browser Back button should redirect to previous page after Form submit

Tags: php, laravel, forms, browser

I'm getting an issue related to browser back button in following scenario:

- User select a product from product list page and redirected to product detail page.
- On detail page, user added product in cart using POST form.
- User has to click  browser back button as many times he submitted form. If he submitted form 3 times to and he has to click back button 3 times to go back to product list page.

I'm using Laravel cart, on form submission I'm redirection user back to the page he came from. Any solution?

Comment: Currently I've fixed this issue by submitting form via AJAX. If anyone can tell me a better solution will be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: When user came on Product detail, save URL of that product in session. And then return user to the URL from session. Its one of the solutions. Maybe not best, but it will work.